# How to display live data in iphone app?

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, screen-scraping, live

I am building an iphone app for my local high school football team. What is the best way to show live data for the scores of games without using a sql db and having to updated the entire app after every game.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few ways of doing it, one would be to create an rss feed on a remote server, and parse that, and if you wanted realtime updates, you could use push notifications.

Comment: PUSH would certainly be the way to go

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on creating the app to only show what the end result of each game was you can use NSXMLParser as @MCannon suggests. If you plan on having the app update in REAL TIME, as in. "The ball is on the 45 Yard line, 3rd and 3". Then you can stick with NSXMLParser but create a NSTimer to update the information every 30 seconds or so.

That would also mean you would need to have the RSS feed updated in real time as well.

Comment: the way i would do this, is register the app for push notifications, and in the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification refresh the feed.

Comment: Theres a few problems with that. The biggest being the size limit of the APNS. I am not sure how much information you are wanting to push down but it will have to be minimal. I guess if you just wanted to update the score, and then have them open the app if they wanted more information and at that time pull down an xml file with more info.

Comment: I would pass down a short string of who scored for which team, and in the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification, have it update from the feed where there is more info as this is only called if the app is running, or if the app is started from the notification.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you're asking is to have the data stored on the internet in some fashion, then build into your app a routine for consulting the remote data source (on the internet) and update its internal storage accordingly.

It can be done with no DB but the data must exist and be accessible over the internet. As others have suggested, an RSS feed would be a great way to pipe in the data.